# Invalid mex file: undefined symbol: cholmod_camd

Tags: linux, matlab, mex, ceres-solver

How to solve this issue? I saw no cholmod_camd related header file in the c++ file I was trying to mex.

```
Invalid MEX-file '/home/mpelang/Desktop/APAPstitch/Image Stitching with 
Bundled Moving
DLT/ceresRigidError.mexa64': /usr/local/lib/libceres.so: undefined 
symbol:
cholmod_camd
```

Answer (score 0):

Ceres solver needs Cholesky methods for solving the linear systems. Either link the c++ file against a library containing cholmod_camd (with -lcholmod -lmwlapack) or explicitly tell ceres you have no cholmod (when building ceres using cmake). Take a look at http://ceres-solver.org/installation.html for how to install Ceres-solver.